# How to perform homography between image points & CAD model points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the coordinates of 4 points of an object in an image and the coordinates of the same points on a 2D projection of the object's 3D model in FreeCAD.

points_image =[[1,2392],[2459,2497],[2453,554],[183,437]]
points_model = [[-107,-100], [92,-100], [89,62], [-104,62]]

Of course, the coordinate systems are different.
I need to perform homography between the two sets of points.
The goal is to select any point of the model and be able to project it on the image (and vice versa)

My problem mostly lies on the **normalization** and **de-normalization** of the points before and after the homography (which I do using cv2.findHomography)
Has anyone done this before?

Comment: what's the issue? tack a 1 onto the input points, run through the matrix, then divide the result by its last dimension, and you're back on the canonical plane. opencv has a routine for all of that: cv.perspectiveTransform()

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of performing homography between the two sets of points with the following steps:

I read and saved the height of the image using OpenCV's cv2.imread() function and then used the .shape attribute of the resulting NumPy array.

```
image_2 = cv2.imread('image_2.png')
image_height, _, _ = image_2.shape
```

I flipped the y-coordinates of the image points to account for the different orientation of the y-axis in the image and model coordinate systems.

```
points_image[:, 1] = image_height - points_image[:, 1]
```

I computed the normalization scales for my model and image points by calculating the distance between the first and third points of the point sets, which are diagonally opposite each other.

```
def compute_scale(points):
    point1, point3 = points[0], points[2]
    return np.sqrt((point1[0] - point3[0]) ** 2 + (point1[1] - point3[1]) ** 2)

scale_model = compute_scale(points_model)
scale_image = compute_scale(points_image)
```

I normalized my points.

```
normalized_points_model = points_model / scale_model
normalized_points_image = points_image / scale_image
```

I computed the homography matrix using the normalized points with OpenCV's cv2.findHomography() function.

```
h_normalized, _ = cv2.findHomography(normalized_points_model, normalized_points_image)
```

I defined a function to project a point from the model's coordinate system to the image's coordinate system using the computed homography matrix.

```
def project_point(point, h):
    point = np.append(point, 1)
    new_point_homog = np.dot(h, point)
    return new_point_homog[:2] / new_point_homog[2]
```

I selected a point from my model, normalized it, projected it to the image's coordinate system, and then denormalized it.

```
random_model_point = np.float32([24,-45])
normalized_random_model_point = random_model_point / scale_model
projected_point = project_point(normalized_random_model_point, h_normalized)
denormalized_projected_point = projected_point * scale_image
denormalized_projected_point[1] = image_height - denormalized_projected_point[1]
```

Finally, I visualized the projected point on my image by drawing a circle at the projected point's coordinates.

```
image_2 = cv2.circle(image_2, (int(denormalized_projected_point[0]), int(denormalized_projected_point[1])), radius=5, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=-1)
```

I also resized the image to fit my screen using cv2.resize() before displaying it with cv2.imshow().

I made sure to convert my points to np.float32 before any computations to avoid integer division.